# Facebook LoginFragment - no view found color/accent_material_dark

Tags: android, facebook

I implemented Facebook share in my android app and it's working well.
But I'm having problem with `postid`, it's always returning null and I know the reason: because user must login in to the app. So I wrote this code:

```
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("publish_actions");
            manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
            manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(activity, permissions);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{gjirafa.com/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08000f (gjirafa.com:color/accent_material_dark) for fragment     
LoginFragment{41da8178 #0 id=0x7f08000f SingleFragment}
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 13:30:05.784: E/AndroidRuntime(25049): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08000f (gjirafa.com:color/accent_material_dark) for fragment  
LoginFragment{41da8178 #0 id=0x7f08000f SingleFragment}
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace in your question instead of a picture of part of the stack trace.

Comment: @apmartin1991 edited

Comment: can you now post how you are loading your LoginFragment

Comment: @apmartin1991 im just calling this 
            manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(activity, permissions);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I used [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing) library to authorizate the user to facebook.